# View PDF without downloading

Tags: html, pdf, mobile, browser, pdf.js

I am building a simple website (hosted internally on my home network) to view a bunch of PDF files on any device.

Sample page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>PDF Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<body>

<a href="test.pdf">Click here to open PDF</a>

</body>
</html>
```

On a **desktop browser** (Firefox & Chrome), the link opens the PDF directly in the same tab in the browser *without* downloading the file (provided the `Content-Type: application/pdf`).

On a **mobile browser** (Android Firefox & Chrome), the link downloads the PDF file and clutters the device. On iOS Safari, the PDF is opening inline in the browser.

I would like a consistent experience of *viewing the PDF without downloading* on any device. It appears that the only option is embed [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) on the website - similar to [this page](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html), which opens PDF files inside the browser from all desktop and mobile browsers.

Am I on the right track? Is this the only option?

ps: when I say *without downloading*, I mean it should not auto download into the Downloads folder of the device and clutter the disk storage.

Comment: You can't view ANY document without downloading it or some version of it.

Comment: Of course, every byte gets downloaded/transferred over the network. I have edited to clarify "without downloading".

Answer (score 0):

To try to explain remote PDF viewing here is a more visible even if unorthodox view
I have selected a local file in the local browser so one could expect it would open "inline" without need for download, that would be how it looks in Edge, instant file loading.

[image]

However my browser is not the default local viewer so the file is offered as a download for save, I can over-ride that by set browser to default and for a local file it will not need to download a working copy.

Likewise, if I select a Lan file the local default will load a copy without request, however it is downloaded. Both the browser and viewer are lying to me. To see how I know look at second image below, I asked to save annotations to existing PDF where **normally** I have rights to overwrite a LAN file on remote drive.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can upload your pdf-file on Google drive and embed it with:

```
 <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/{ID}/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

{ID} is the Drive document’s ID (you can get a share link and the id is in the url).